# Avoid detection of the ending point navigation

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I'm using the SKMaps.frameworks from the Scout developer team (which is pretty awesome !) on an IOS swift development.

I use the GPX functions on a turn by turn experience. What I want is to create a loop route. So the starting waypoint and the ending waypoint from my GPX file are at the same coordinates.

My problem is that in these conditions, the RoutingService stop automatically the navigation at the very beginning of my navigation since both points are the same. Everything works fine if I take away the ending point 100 meters far from the starting point but I don't want to do that !

How could I avoid the routingService to detect the destination Point ?

Thank you very much in advance :) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so, like every time when you ask a question, you find the solution few minutes later ... (and I assure this has been a long time I'm dealing with this issue :p !)

Here's what I did : in the `SKMaps.frameworks`, found the `SKNavigationDelegate` header and comment (or delete) the line :

```
//- (void)routingServiceDidReachDestination:(SKRoutingService *)routingService;
```

It seems to works now. Hope it could help someone :)

Comment: how i can do same in Android? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also modify the advices to remove the "@" switch at the end of the last advice - this will stop the SDK from automatically stopping the navigation once the last advice is played: for details see these articles: [here](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/) and [here](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-faq/)

Comment: Thank you for your additional answer ;)